# Adding custom form to form_alter -- help please

Tags: forms

I've been trying for awhile to add a custom form to a custom module so as to make it show in drupal profile Edit page. Using the normal $form['submit'] messes up the other forms in the page, so tried to use $form['#submit'][] and append the second submit handler, but still no luck. Hoping someone can see what i am doing wrong.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form' && user_access('delete mods', $form['#user'])) {

$modlist = getcurrentmods(); // this function returns an array of usernames

$form['modlist']['mods'] = array(
'#type'=>'select',
'#options' => $modlist,
'#multiple' => false,
'#weight' => 30,
'#size' => 10,
'#id' => 'modlist',
'#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-modlist">',
'#suffix' => '</div>',
 );

$form['#submit'][] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Delete'),
'#submit' => array('_modlist_delete_callback'),
'#weight' => 32,
'#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('submit-inline'),
),
'#ajax' => array('callback' => '_modlist_delete_callback',
'wrapper' => 'dropdown-modlist',
'effect' => 'fade',
'method' => 'replace',
  ),
 );

  }
}
```

The dropdown with the user list shows up fine, however the submit button doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Anything with a # preceding it isn't an element, it's a property. Properties are not rendered.

To fix, just give your submit button a unique key without the #, e.g.

```
$form['foo_submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  ...
);
```

Comment: I tried changing it to $form['modlist']['submit'] , however this submits the main form and shows the message "The specified passwords do not match." from the Profile page, not part of my custom form.

Comment: Sorry i am a bit new to drupal so i could be wrong, but isn't it possible to add a form to the profile edit page that does its own form submission unrelated to main Profile2 form?

Comment: It's...murky :) The form isn't being 'submitted' in Drupal terms here, as in the submit handlers aren't running, but the _validation_ handlers still are. That's where the error message comes from. You can't stop the validation handlers running (without some hackery) but you can suppress the errors by adding `'#limit_validation_errors' => array()` to the element. I think that'll get you what you're looking for

Comment: Ah, cool. I think that's what we need. Many thanks for the help :)